# Strange type conversion from List[(Char, Char)] to Object

Tags: java, scala, jvm, jvm-languages

I have a recursive function `count` in Scala 2.9.2 that looks like this

```
def count(traces: Seq[(Char, Char)], acc: (TP, TN, FP, FN)): (TP, TN, FP, FN) = {
  val (tp, tn, fp, fn) = acc
  traces match {
    case Nil => acc
    case ('(', '(')::rest => count(rest, (tp + 1, tn, fp, fn))
    case (')', ')')::rest => count(rest, (tp + 1, tn, fp, fn))
    case ('(', ')')::rest => count(rest, (tp, tn + 1, fp, fn))
    // ... exhaustive set of cases ...
  }
}
```

On input `Seq(('(', '('))` the function throws the following `MatchError`:

```
scala.MatchError: Vector(((,()) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Vector)
```

I investigated this by playing around with the code in the Scala console.

```
scala> val t = Seq(('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'))
t: Seq[(Char, Char)] = List((a,b), (b,c))

scala> t match { case Nil => "h"; case ('a', 'b')::rest => rest }
res6: java.lang.Object = List((b,c))

scala> t1 match { case Nil => "h"; case ('a', 'b')::rest => rest }
scala.MatchError: List((b,c)) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

It seems as if matching `('a', 'b')::rest` (the second line) doesn't return an object of the correct type, since the `Seq[(Char, Char)]` is suddenly of type `java.lang.Object` which Scala then doesn't know how to match on.

What explains this behavior?

Comment: 1) Seq in general is not guaranteed to support :: extractors, it's only Lists thing 2) Are you sure you haven't forgot about tuple+empty tail case? 3)In your second console example you're trying to return string "h" and at the same time rest which is `Seq[(String,String)]`.  The only common supertype is java.lang.Object (or, Any in scala kingdom).

Comment: 1) Didn't know that. Using List instead solved the problem completely! 2) That case shouldn't be necessary. 3) That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation :-) Would you mind submitting 1 as an answer so I can give you proper credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your pattern matching is that you use [extractors](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) [defined only for List class](http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/11/25/scala-list-extractor-demystified) but passing to them Vector.

If you really need to match against every possible Seq, you may want to use general syntax:

```
   foo match {
     case Seq('(' -> ')',rest@ _* ) => println("The tail is" + rest)
   }
```

(Don't be confused with `->` arrow, `1 -> 2` is essentially the same as `(1,2)`, but in this particular case much more readable: you will not mess usual braces with `'('` and `')'` like in `Seq(('(',')'), ... )`)

Otherwise, just [strict](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.immutable.png) your argument type to List[(Char, Char)].

Comment: In 2.10 one can do: `foo {case Seq() => ... case ('a', 'b') +: rest => ...}`