# Scala: toSeq vs Seq(something:_*)

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I wrote a function named *extract*, defined as follows:

```
def extract(params: String): Seq[String] = {
  val result = params.split(",") map (param => param.trim())
  result toSeq
}
```

Then I perform pattern matching over *extract* result, like this:

```
extract(myInputString) match {
  case Nil => // do something
  case head :: Nil => // do something
  case head :: tail => // do something
}
```

whenever my pattern matches **case Nil =>** branch, I get a

```
scala.MatchError: WrappedArray(T) (of class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef)
```

on the other hand, if I replace **result toSeq** with **Seq(result:_*)** in *extract* function, everything works fine.

Can anyone explain this behaviour please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange type conversion from List\[(Char, Char)\] to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754800/strange-type-conversion-from-listchar-char-to-object)

Comment: In short, by writing head::Nil, you instruct pattern matching to wait a **List**, but not all Seq's are Lists (e.g. WrappedArray **is not a** List). See link above. To make this work you may replace `.toSeq` with `.toList`.

Comment: @om-nom-nom thanks for your answer but I already found a solution to my problem (replacing **result toSeq** with **Seq(result:_*)**), I was just wondering why would that happen because (as far as I know), **::** extractor pattern should be supported for all sequences, even if they are not Lists...

Comment: `toList` is slower - maybe because it does a copy. I did not test for matching, though

Comment: @Freidereikhs you have wrong info -- `::` extractor defined **only for list**

Comment: @Freidereikhs the :: is an extractor for Lists only; in fact, Lists are abstract classes with only two concrete classes: `Nil` and `::` (yes, `::` is a class with header `final case class ::[B](private var hd: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B])`). Check its type at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1.

Comment: @idonnie as far as I know Seq(list:_*) is doing copy as well, but varargs slows things down. Because of that for some collections there is "specialized* companion factories for one, two elements and some other. See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/g_-gIWgB8Os/HeQzfOo6keEJ). Maybe Rex could clarify some points?

Comment: @om-nom-nom I've benchmarked, `toList` and `Seq(result: _*)` - they're both the same, and `toSeq` is faster. But combined with actually pattern-match, using `Seq()`, `Seq(a, _*)`, `Seq(a)` with `toSeq`, and `Nil`, `h :: Nil`, `h :: t` with `toList` - all the same. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`Nil` and `::` are extractors that only match instances of type `List`. You are passing a `Seq`, which is a more general trait that may or may not be a `List`.

When you construct a `Seq` using `Seq(...)`, Scala builds a `List` by default. The same cannot be said of `toSeq`, which usually encapsulates the underlying collection in the most adequate `Seq` interface. For example, `Iterator.toSeq` yields a `Stream`, while `Array.toSeq` yields a `WrappedArray`.

That's why your code doesn't work when you call `toSeq`; `String.split` yields an `Array` (it's a method from the original Java `String` class), and `map` maintains its type. You can either add a case to deal with instances of `Seq` or make your `extract` method return a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

For general `Seq`s you do the match as follows:

```
extract(myInputString) match { 
  case Seq() => ...
  case Seq(head) => ...
  case Seq(head, tail @ _*) => ...
}
```

Scala 2.10 has extractors for `Seq` equivalent to those on `List`, so just replace `Nil` with `Seq()` and `::` with `+:` and it'll work:

```
extract(myInputString) match {
  case Seq() => ...
  case head +: Seq() => ...
  case head +: tail => ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOW, ULTIMATE MATCH**

```
extract("a, b") match { 
  case Seq() => "0"
  case Seq(a, b, _*) => "many"
  case Seq(a, _*) => "1"
}
```

And, again I have a little suspicion - everything is a `List` here.

**...**

`toList`, or your variant of `Seq(someething: _*)` will create again, a `List`

Comment: Did you mean `Seq()`? That would match an empty `Seq`, but he would still have problems in the second and third cases.

Comment: Umm I though that the problem is only for `Nil` =)

Comment: I would prefer `toList`, because it has much more obvious intent and more performant than varargs, although not so much. And maybe write pattern matching as something like `case Seq() => ... case Seq(head) => ... case Seq(head, tail: _*) => ` if no conversion to list was done?

Comment: How? You foresaw my Ultimate Match ?? ^)